# C# ASP.NET Update Progress not showing

Tags: c#, asp.net, updatepanel, ascx, updateprogress

I have this code in my control it is basically a control where the user enters a postcode and then clicks the check availability button - this then in turn calls an API and displays the address details in the update panel below.

```
<asp:UpdatePanel runat="server" UpdateMode="Conditional" ID="UpdatePanel_PostCode">

        <ContentTemplate>

            <asp:Panel runat="server" ID="Panel_PostCode" CssClass="form-row group" >
                <div class="textbox-group">
                        <div class="textbox-group-row">
                            <div class="label-textbox">
                                <asp:Label runat="server" ID="Label_PostCodeToCheck" AssociatedControlID="TextBox_PostCodeToCheck"
                                    Text="Postcode"></asp:Label>
                            </div>
                            <div class="input-text">
                                <asp:TextBox runat="server" ID="TextBox_PostCodeToCheck"></asp:TextBox>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                        <div class="textbox-group-row">
                            <div class="find-address">
                                <span class="extra">
                                    <asp:Button runat="server" ID="Button_AddressCheck" CssClass="button dis small"
                                        Text="Find Address" OnClick="Button_AddressCheck_OnClick"  ClientIDMode="AutoID"/>
                                </span>
                            </div>
                            <div class="input-text">
                                    <asp:UpdateProgress ID="progressPanel" runat="server" AssociatedUpdatePanelID="UpdatePanel_PostCode">
                                        <ProgressTemplate>
                                            <div id="CheckAvailMsg" runat="server" style="height: 24px; margin-top: 0.5em;">
                                                <img id="ImageLoading" width="24px" height="24px" src="../images/loading.gif" alt="" style="float: left; padding-right: 0.5em;" />
                                                <p id="domainCheckerText" style="float: left; padding-top: 0.3em; color: #000;">Checking Availability..</p>
                                            </div>
                                        </ProgressTemplate>
                                    </asp:UpdateProgress>
                                </div>
                        </div>
                        <asp:Panel ID="Panel_Error" runat="server" CssClass="error" Visible="False">
                            <asp:Literal runat="server" ID="Literal_Error"></asp:Literal>
                        </asp:Panel>

                    </div>

            </asp:Panel>

        </ContentTemplate>
    </asp:UpdatePanel>
```

However when I click the Find address button the Update progress does not show - i've exhausted a number of resources but still cannot find a solution.

Comment: Can you remove `Panel1` and keep progresspanel out out that control!

Comment: Hi there, thank you for your response. I have removed the Panel1 (I think that was added by mistake) However it still appears that the update progress is showing. Do you mean remove it from the update panel entirely?

Comment: You have written, it is showing :) , no I don't mean to remove update panel, make sure you have `ScriptManager` included and try moving `UpdateProgress` out of `UpdatePanel`.

Comment: Ahh ok. Im not sure what you mean by ScriptManager. Would you be able to give an example. That would be much appreciated :)

Comment: check this - https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb399001(v=vs.140).aspx, http://www.codeproject.com/Questions/155475/How-to-use-ScriptManager-and-updatePanel-associate